# -Wpointer-to-int-cast and -Wint-conversion warning in C p thread program

Tags: c, pthreads

I have created a program to matrix multiplication using C in pthread. But when i compile my program i get some warning and note. I tried my best to solve this. I was unable to do this. I mentioned my warning and  note below.

`warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]`  `int s = (int)threadid;`

`warning: passing argument 1 of ‘multiply’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`      `multiply(i);`

`note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 void* multiply(void *threadid)`

[warning and note image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ626.png)

code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 1024

int num_thrd;

int A[SIZE][SIZE], B[SIZE][SIZE], C[SIZE][SIZE];

int randnumgen(){
  return rand()%10 +1 ;
}

void init_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE])
{
 int i, j, val = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 {
   for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
   {
     m[i][j] = randnumgen();
   }
  }
}

void print_matrix(int m[SIZE][SIZE])
{
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
  printf("\n\t| ");
  for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
     printf("%2d ", m[i][j]);
     printf("|");
   }
}

// thread function
void* multiply(void *threadid)
{  
  int s = (int)threadid;
  int from = (s * SIZE)/num_thrd;
  int to = ((s+1) * SIZE)/num_thrd;
  int i,j,k;

  clock_t begin = clock();

  for (i = from; i < to; i++)
  {  
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
      C[i][j] = 0;
      for ( k = 0; k < SIZE; k++)
      C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
  }


  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  pthread_t* thread;
  int i;
  double runtime=0;

  num_thrd = atoi(argv[1]);
  init_matrix(A);
  init_matrix(B);
  thread = (pthread_t*) malloc(num_thrd*sizeof(pthread_t));


  clock_t begin = clock();

   for (i = 0; i < num_thrd; i++){

    multiply(i);
   }

  clock_t end = clock();
  runtime = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("%f\n",runtime);

  free(thread);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You're missing a call to the *`pthread_create`* i.e. you're not actually threading anything. You could change `int` to `intptr_t` in the problematic place, and `multiply(i)` needs an *explicit cast to* `void*` though note that you're not even supposed to directly call the `multiply`function - the pthread library is supposed to do it

Comment: While you can pass integers to the thread function like that, it gets messy.  You'd do better using an intermediary `uintptr_t` cast — in the thread function, cast the pointer argument to `uintptr_t`, and then convert the result to `int`, leading to: `int s = (int)(uintptr_t)threadid;` and remembering to include either `<stdint.h>` or `<inttypes.h>`.  Alternatively, pass a pointer to where the information is stored, making sure each thread has its own storage.